# Delete rows from Worksheet A if a condition is satisfied in Worksheet B

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to do as the question say, namely I have two worksheets with similar data. However, in worksheet B, when i have a condition, say a column for me to type "Done". It would  delete the same data with this condition satisfied in worksheet A.

My macro:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim SO As String
Dim Balance As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
Dim ItsAMatch As Boolean
Dim i As Integer

Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Customer Specific Stock")
Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stock (Data)")
SO = Source.Range("K3")


Do Until IsEmpty(Target.Cells(2 + i, 5)) ' This will loop down through non empty cells from row 2 of column 4
    If Source.Cells(2 + i, 5) = SO Then
        ItsAMatch = True
        Target.Cells(2 + i, 1) = ""
        Target.Cells(2 + i, 2) = ""
        Target.Cells(2 + i, 3) = ""
        Target.Cells(2 + i, 4) = ""
        Target.Cells(2 + i, 5) = "" 
        Target.Cells(2 + i, 6) = ""
        Target.Cells(2 + i, 7) = ""
        Target.Cells(2 + i, 8) = "" ' This will overwrite your the value if PO is covered
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

Set Source = Nothing
Set Target = Nothing



End Sub
```

It does not work at all. Where have i gone wrong? Another question is when I put a macro in a module, how do i use it with the command button?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is with the statement "Exit Do." Because you exit the loop when the match condition is met, your code will delete only the first match. If you eliminate that, it will instead run through all the non-empty cells. I made a simplified version of what I think your data might look like:

[image]

[image]

Here is the adapted code:

```
Sub Stack()
Dim SO As String
Dim Balance As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
Dim ItsAMatch As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Customer Specific Stock")
Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stock (Data)")
SO = "Done"
i = 0
Do Until IsEmpty(Target.Cells(2 + i, 1)) ' This will loop down through non empty cells from row 2 of column 4
On Error Resume Next
If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Cells(2 + i, 1), Source.Range("A1:B100"), 2, False) = SO Then
    ItsAMatch = True
    Target.Cells(2 + i, 1) = ""
    Target.Cells(2 + i, 2) = ""
    Target.Cells(2 + i, 3) = ""
    Target.Cells(2 + i, 4) = ""
    Target.Cells(2 + i, 5) = ""
    Target.Cells(2 + i, 6) = ""
    Target.Cells(2 + i, 7) = ""
    Target.Cells(2 + i, 8) = ""
End If
On Error GoTo 0
i = i + 1
Loop
Set Source = Nothing
Set Target = Nothing
End Sub
```

Running this blanks out the rows of animals that have already been fed, resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Hi Liza, Thanks for helping. The code is working fine. I would like to just ask, if now the columns i have are not only "Animal" and "Fed". Maybe I have a "Time" too. However, I would only want to delete the entries in the target cells only depending on one column, ie "Time". How do i do it?

Comment: or rather, what if the animals column are not arranged the same in both worksheets?

Comment: If they are not in the same order, you could replace "If Source.Cells(2 + i, 2) = SO Then" with "If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Cells(2 + i, 1), Source.Range("A1:B100"), 2, False) = SO Then" That way your code will take the value in Column A of "Stock(Data)", look for it in Column A of "Customer Specific Stock" and delete the values in "Stock(Data)" if Column B for that row in "Customer Specific Stock" reads "Done."

Comment: Most likely that means that, either, you've structured your VLookUp function incorrectly, or for at least one of the entries in Stock(Data) there is no exact match in Customer Specific Stock. You'll need to decide what you want your code to do if no match is found. I edited my answer to allow the code to continue running even when no match is found, but this is going to cause it to blank out the row both when the condition is met and when no match is found. I suggest that you play around with VLookup and error handling and then create a new question if you run into problems.